# How to prove the inner product of complex vectors is conjugate-symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

For complex vector-space of 2 dimensions, prove that the inner product is conjugate-symmetric, ie:

$$
< \underline{x},\underline{z}> = <\underline{z},\underline{x}>^{*}
$$

where:

$$
\underline{x} = \begin{bmatrix}
          x_1 \\
          x_2 \\
         \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\underline{z} = \begin{bmatrix}
          z_1 \\
          z_2 \\
         \end{bmatrix}
$$

A few things provided by the book:

- **Hermitian Conjugate, aka. Conjugate-Transpose**:

$$\underline{A}^H = ( \underline{A}^T )^*$$

- **For Complex Vectors: Inner Product, aka. Dot Product**:
  $$<\underline{x}, \underline{z}> = \underline{x}^H \underline{z}$$
- **For Real Vectors: Inner Product, aka. Dot Product**:
  $$<\underline{x}, \underline{z}> = \underline{x}^T \underline{z}$$

Comment: Did you try to set $x = a + i\cdot b$ and $y = c + i \cdot d$ and apply the inner product?

Comment: $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ being a 2x1 vectors?

Comment: Yes, you can do that for vectors, scalars or matrices.

Comment: well, i'm told that inner product has both linear and anti-linear properties: $$<\alpha\vec{x} + \beta\vec{y}, \vec{z}> = \alpha^*<\vec{x},\vec{z}> + \beta^*<\vec{y},\vec{z}>$$  $$<\vec{z}, \alpha\vec{x} + \beta\vec{y}> = \alpha<\vec{z},\vec{x}> + \beta<\vec{z},\vec{y}>$$

Comment: Well use linearity and antilinearity on the real and imaginary decomposition and you should get your result.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{aligned}
<\underline{x},\underline{z}> &= \underline{x}^H \underline{z} \\
\\
<\underline{x},\underline{z}> &= \begin{bmatrix} x_1^* & x_2^* \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} z_1 \\ z_2 \end{bmatrix} \\
\\
<\underline{x},\underline{z}> &= x_1^* z_1 + x_2^* z_2 
\end{aligned}
$$

---

$$
\begin{aligned}
<\underline{z},\underline{x}> &= \underline{z}^H \underline{x} \\
\\
<\underline{z},\underline{x}> &= \begin{bmatrix} z_1^* & z_2^* \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} \\
\\
<\underline{z},\underline{x}> &= z_1^* x_1 + z_2^* x_2 
\end{aligned}
$$

---

Now we ask, how can we make these two products equivalent...

$$
<z,x>^* = (z_1^* x_1 + z_2^* x_2)^* = (z_1 x_1^* + z_2 x_2^*) = (x_1^* z_1  + x_2^* z_2 ) = <x,z> $$